# Does a Capital X Mean Anything in Integration (when among lower case x's)?

Tags: notation

I was reading [this article about integration](http://web.archive.org/web/20180219002102/https://www.math.uri.edu/%7Eeaton/mth142sp02rational.pdf) (via web.archive) and decided to do the excercises when I realized something strange. Some of the X's are capitalized in excercises 3, 4, and 5. Here are the examples so you don't have to read the article.
$$\int \frac{X^3-2X}{x+1} dx$$
$$\int \frac{x^4+3X^2}{2x-3} dx$$
$$\int \frac{x^2-X}{x^2+4} dx$$
Does this mean anything in calculus texts, like a separate variable? Or is this probably just a typo? The author does not have any capital X's in the article itself.

Comment: bad link err 404

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to fix it, although I am unsure how as it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author made a typo and meant $x$ when he said $X$.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I needed the confirmation.